# Arrays and passing it to a function

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define K 4
#define n 16


bool search(int *t, int size, int val)
{
    int nb_element_per_stage;
    if (val < t[0] || val > t[size - 1])
    {
        return false;
    }

    int inf = 0;
    int sup = size - 1;

    if (sup - inf + 1 > K)
    {
        nb_element_per_stage = (sup - inf + 1) / K;
        sup = (sup - inf + 1) / K - 1;

        while (inf < sup - inf + 1)
        {
            if (val >= t[inf] && val <= t[sup])
            {
                return search(t, sup - inf + 1, val);
            }
            else
            {
                inf = sup + 1;
                sup = sup + nb_element_per_stage;
            }
        }
        if (inf == sup - inf + 1)
            return false;
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < sup - inf + 1; i++)
            {
                if (val == t[i])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `t[inf]` and `t[sup]` are always pointing to the first two values of `sup` and `inf` of the bigger array.

How do I properly pass the array with the new size? Also is `t[0]` of the old one is the same `t[0]` of the new one?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to search on a sorted array, based on `val<t[0]||val>t[size-1]` if condition. Why can't you use binary search?

Comment: if it was for me i'd use it right but it's a home work, can't argue with that :p

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code so it is readable.  As it stands, it is unreadable.

Comment: Your call/return `return search(t, sup - inf + 1, val);` should probably be `return search(&t[inf], sup - inf + 1, val);` — but you should probably be using a normal binary search.

Comment: I observe that you're missing at least a closing brace and probably a `return false;` before the end of the code you submitted.  I formatted what you gave — and double checked it when I noticed the missing brace at the end.  It just emphasizes that it is important to format code cleanly from the start.

Comment: it's still pointing to the first values, and i cannot use binary search

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: if it added this  printf("%d",t[inf]);
            printf("%d",t[sup]); after the while it always give me the first ones

Comment: Why can't you implement binary search? What are you supposed to do? Is the array sorted? Can you post a precise description of your assignment?

Comment: Part of the code is missing: what do you do if `sup - inf + 1 <= K`?